# Unable to redirect to 404 for some random urls which are not there in routes.php, laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If Link(**http://*******.in/email/t/X**) is not found in routes.php it should be redirected to 404, but is redirecting to some black page [Image reference for the black screen & rendered html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U019P.png)

```
Request URL: http://*******.in/email/t/X
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> Weird thing is **http://********.in/email/t** is redirecting to 404, but the mentioned url is not redirecting to 404

Comment: put this code in your route Route::get('{slug}', function() {
  return view('errors.404');
})->where('slug', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\%\~\@\#\$\^\&\*\(\)\+\.\>\<\:\;\"/]+)');

Comment: @pal It didn't work, still redirecting to the black screen

Comment: Could you show us what your routes are?

Comment: @DelenaMalan It is a long file & not supposed to post it here due to the project security issues. Sorry for that, but I can assure you that it doesn't have the word "email" in it.

Comment: @DelenaMalan I tried removing all the route declarations in routes.php file, but still the same black screen (If some route exists in dynamic way it should be redirected to 404)